# How can i take a mutiples value from selected option and put into text area with line break

Tags: javascript

I already using this code block

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <small>Clique para selecionar e/ou retirar um produto desejado</small>
    <select name="id_produtos" data-label="Produtos" id="produtos" class="form-control show-tick pl-4 pr-4 pb-4 " data-live-search="true" multiple>
        <option value="" disabled>Selecione um produto</option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Produtos)
        {
            <option value="@item.id_produto">@item.nome</option>
        }
    </select>
    <small>Produtos Selecionados</small>
    @*<label id="produtos-selecionados" class="mm-yyyy form-control"> </label>*@
    <textarea id="produtos-selecionados" class="mm-yyyy form-control" rows="10" cols="40"  minlength="10" maxlength="25" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```

***and this script:***

```
$('select[name="id_produtos"]').change(function () {
        var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        if (text != "") {
            text = text;

        }

        $('#produtos-selecionados').val(text);
    });
```

But didn't take a line break in text area.

Please help me guys, thanks BTW.

Comment: why not adding a line break to `text` ?

Comment: `$(this).find("option:selected")` would get one or more elements. So the `.text()` on more than one element might by problematic. Why not use jQuery's `.map()` function, especially the first example on https://api.jquery.com/map/. This example gets all `id`s from the elements in the collection, but you can adjust that to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).find("option:selected")` would get one or more elements. So the `.text()` on more than one element might by problematic.
You might be able to do this with jQuery's `.map().get().join()` chain. This way you have more control of the line break characters in between the values.

Like so:

```js
$('select[name="id_produtos"]').change(function() {
    var v = $(this).find('option:selected') // Get all selected options
    .map(function() { // For each option return the label text only
        return this.innerText; // or use this.value if that's what you want
    })
    .get() // Get as an array
    .join("\n"); // Join/glue together with line breaks

    $('textarea').val( v ); // Set textarea contents
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="id_produtos" multiple>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<textarea rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: Work perfect, Thanks for thar bro.